# How to add a font awesome icon next to a printf

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I am trying to add a font awesome icon in the following line right before the author variable:

```
<?php printf($author);
```

in which $author calls on

```
$author = sprintf( __( 'by %s', 'themename' ), $author_link );
```

I am not sure how I can add the following i tags

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in printf function. Is it right to add it to the printf function at all?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: doing something like <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php printf($author); ?> does not work ?

Comment: Thanks, but it does not.

Comment: Are you loading properly the FA, cause the previous comment should do it.

Comment: Yes, it was due of font awesome. thanks